# Renamed Files Still Exist in Xcode

Tags: iphone

I'm making an iphone app that displays a random picture chosen from pictures in Resources.

I have renamed some files for categorization, 
but running console shows that file with a new name and file with old name both exist as separate files.
Of course, I can't see the file with the old name in my Resource folder, nor in the original folder where the pictures are.
Kinda freaky...

How could I remove the files with old names and make it a norm to not keep another file with the old name whenever I rename a file?

Please help me out.

Thanx.

Comment: Are you sure the file is actually there? could be just caching.

Comment: but trying NSLog with filenames shows that both exist.. anyway I could remove those?

Comment: Could this be something to do with confusing a folder reference and an Xcode group in the project - using one when you wanted the other? The only visual difference is that they are a different color. Either will work but you manage the content differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand your Target and remove the images from **Copy Bundle Resources**.

Comment: Delete the app from your device/simulator and clean your targets. If the old filenames are not in that Copy Bundle Resources, then you should be good after.

Comment: how do I delete the app from device/simulator?

Comment: is that the one under Products folder?

Comment: also, do i need to clean the Compilse Sources and Link Binary With Library as well?

Comment: On the device and Simulator, hold the icons till they wiggle, then remove your app. Simple. The **Copy Bundle Resources** folder under Targets is the only place you need to mess with files *(if you are having issues)*, so leave the other 2 alone.

Comment: btw, i accidentally deleted files in Compile Sources folder, howdo I recover those? or does it not matter?

Comment: those are mostly classes, so when you go to build your project, Xcode will bitch about missing classes, just re-add them from your project folder on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I recommend cleaning your targets from the project menu and resetting the simulator.

You can also select all the new files in XCode, right click and select compile.